# jquery ajax call not triggering in bootstrap typehead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I trying to do a twitter bootstrap typehead using Ajax, but nothin happens.No error no output
Here is my jquery ajax code

```
    function CallData() {

    $('input.typeahead.local.remote').typeahead({
        source: function (typeahead,query) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://cs-api-sandbox.herokuapp.com/v1/challenges/search?keyword=r&callback=my_callback",
                jsonpCallback: "my_callback",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
                    var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
                    alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

function my_callback(data) {
    alert('hi');
}
```

Here is my html code

```
<input type="text" id="txt" runat="server" class="span4 typeahead local remote" placeholder="Search..." />
```

i'm calling the ajax function `CallData()` on each key press but nothing happens

Comment: Does any of the `alert()` calls get triggered?

Comment: no it doesn't get triggered

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the result from the ajax request to the second argument of source (which is a callback to populate the type ahead).  A contrived example:

```
$('#mytypeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/some/url?query='+query,
            success: function(response){
                process(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `async: false` into the $.ajax - because the mechanisms of javascript is unsynchronized.
Hope this help